# IntelliJ Idea 11 Flex compilation issue

Tags: java, apache-flex, intellij-idea, flex4.5, socketexception

I have problem with completing my code. It works fine in Flash Builder. But I used it previously in Idea and it was much faster. So I imported my FB files into new Idea project. But when I try to debug I receive error message:

Using built-in compiler shell, up to 4 parallel threads
See compiler settings at File | Settings | Compiler | Flex Compiler page

Starting Flex compiler:
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -d32 -Dapplication.home=/Applications/Adobe/flex_sdk_4 -Xmx384m -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.awt.headless=true -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=en -Xmx512m -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 11.app/plugins/flex/lib/idea-flex-compiler-fix.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 11.app/plugins/flex/lib/flex-compiler.jar:/Applications/Adobe/flex_sdk_4/lib/flex-compiler-oem.jar" com.intellij.flex.compiler.FlexCompiler 58789

Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings

**java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out**

I tried to restart my computer. I have clean OS installation and I don't have any program that should block it.

If it helps I develop on OS X 10.7

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just did a fresh install of IDEA 11.1.3 and Flex SDK 4.6 and got this error with a brand-new Flash Mobile app+module.

Here's how I fixed it:

1. Go to **Settings > Compiler > Flex Compiler**
2. Choose **Mxmlc/compx** instead of the default **Built-in compiler shell**
   (Screenshot: http://puu.sh/10Nhg)
3. Compile your application

Comment: It works but also remember to unselect "prefer Actionscript Compiler 2.0"

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer above did not work for me, and while the answer provided by Florian Salihovic pointed me in the right direction, I thought I would post the solution here.

This comment on the link provided by Florian Salihovic, [specifically the comment I've linked to directly](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-62377#comment=27-1761131), contains the following solution that worked for me:

1. Find your hostname. You can use `hostname` in your shell.
2. Edit `/etc/hosts` and add `127.0.0.1 <<hostname>>` where `<<hostname>>` is the name reported by the `hostname` command.

I have found that this corrected my issue (on Linux) and should correct the issue on OSX as well. With this, you can use the built-in compiler shell still as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to an issue tracked on Jetbrain's YouTrack [Error while starting Flex compiler](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-62377). You might could check that one.

Comment: There's a comment on that issue by "sumowrestler" he dug deep on this problem and found the underlying cause of the timeouts. Resolved this issue for me: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-62377#comment=27-1761131 The tl;dr; version is add your own machines hostname to your hosts file and pass the loopback address 127.0.0.1